# JQuery on('input') Retrieving data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, kindle-fire, kindle

I think I just have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this works. I'm am trying to create a snippet that validates an input field's entry in real time. The input is inside a Bootstrap popover, and thus no usual forms of date validation are working for me. This will only be used on one device, a Kindle 7, on chrome. what I have so far is

```
        $('#datePicker').on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
            $('[name="start"], [name="end"]').on('input', function(e){

                if(e.key.search(/[0-9]|tab|enter|shift|control|alt/i) >= 0){
                    console.log("Good input:" + e.key);
                }else{
                    console.log("Bad input:" + e.key);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            });

            $('[name="start"], [name="end"]').on('keyup',function(){

                if(this.value.length == 2 || this.value.length == 5){
                    this.value = this.value + "-";
                }
            });
        });
```

My thinking being that the event "input" holds some data about what happened. Through all of my searching though, I have found no such data. I was using "keydown" instead, and it did work perfectly, except that the Kindle's virtual keyboard only returned undefined values, and that's when I was saw someone suggest using "input" instead.

Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Are you actually using `\$` in your code? As that will be causing at least one error.

Comment: Sorry, will edit. I'm doing all this through Perl.

Comment: Creating bindings inside another binding is a code smell personally.  The chance exists for duplicate bindings.  <-- side note

Comment: Also to note, that an 'input' event should only emit from events that resulted in the value of the input to change.  So your key search for things like shift, control, alt; those would never be the case.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind. And the regex was there from when I was using "keydown". I'll be to sure to get rid of it.